# After providing the link to the internal testers, they cannot use the app from Google Play

Tags: google-play-console

I have provided my internal testers the link which is shown in the following image:

[image]

Once clicking that link I am transferred to this page:

[image]

After clicking the install link it directs me to Google play store. But on the Google play store it provides only the install and uninstall  button. I cannot open the app.

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this? It has been more than a week I am having this issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: no. It's still the same